# Problem about "after" method and get value from "Entry" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem with following code because I can't add a variable after method as delay, that is get from user keyboard in entry widget. My python program: In Entry widget you add time in seconds, than you press button and after time in seconds user typed starts an mp3 file.

Here my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from playsound import playsound

def rest():
   sleep= int(label_time.get())
   root.after(sleep,sound)
    
def sound():
    playsound("sirena.mp3")
    
root= tk.Tk()
label_time= tk.Entry(root, bd= 5, justify="center")
label_time.place(x= 40, y= 60)
b_conferma= tk.Button(root, text="GO", command= rest ,bg= "red").place (x= 90, y= 100)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you all

Comment: So what exactly goes wrong when you run this?  If it's just that the delay is much shorter than you expected, that's because `.after()` expects the delay to be in milliseconds - you'd have to multiply the user input by 1000 if you wanted it to be in seconds.

Comment: You haven't bound an event processor to your entry widget to allow you to read user input.   You must create an input process function and bind the action to the function. For a good tutorial on how best to do this see [Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html). The section on events is most helpful.

Comment: Thank you jasonharper , i didn't thought about seconds and milliseconds differences. Now it works.